# How to build a list of unique values from a grid?

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-grid

My form has 2 grids on it. When you select a record from the first grid, it will populate the second grid with related records. This secondary grid has a "PEERGROUP" column, and would contain values like "1", "2", etc.

I need to ensure that a user has selected at least 1 record belonging to every group.

I'm stuck on trying to build a list containing unique Group ID values:

```
function CheckSelectionForGroups(gridName)
{
    //Get rows in grid
    var view = $('#' + gridName).data('kendoGrid').dataSource.view();

    //Array to store the all distinct groups in the grid
    var listOfGroups = [];
    var listIndex = 0;

    //Loop over the rows in the grid
    for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++)
    {
        //If the group is found in our list already, do nothing
        if (listOfGroups[view[i].PEERGROUP])
            continue;

        //If the group was not found in our list, add it to the list.
        listOfGroups[listIndex] = view[i].PEERGROUP;
        listIndex = listIndex + 1;
    }

    //TODO - Loop over user selection 
    //    and compare groups against list of groups
}
```

And here is a screenshot of some values:

[image]

(Note: The array is incomplete, because if I take a screenshot after processing the next row, it would incorrectly contain 3 values: `"1"`, `"1"`, and `"2"`)

So in this case, I want `listOfGroups` to only contain the values `"1"` and `"2"`. The `if` statement inside my `for` loop never evaluates to true. I *suspect* Javascript is casting `"1"` to a `1` and is trying to pull the element from `listOfGroups` at index `1`. But I don't know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object to gather the IDs, then use `Object.keys` to get an array of those IDs:

```
var dummyObject = {};
for (var i = 0; i < view.length; i++) {
    dummyObject[view[i].PEERGROUP] = 0;
}
var listOfGroups = Object.keys(dummyObject);
```